# Getting text and replacing it in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, text

I would like to get the text in the quotation marks and display it.

name "john"

and replace it with what is in a text box

name "Whatever"

this is all in a .txt file

Comment: just look it up:                                                      1. How to get text from a text box                                     2. how to write text to a file                                           in my humble opinion this isn't really worth a SO question to find out, it isn't a very specific question, just google it.

Comment: Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the file line by line, split it word by word and find the double quoted text, replace it with the textbox text.

I have given the code to read and replace. Make a write function at the end to write it back to a txt file.

Usage:

```
Try
     ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
     Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("TestFile.txt")
     Dim line As String
     Dim FullContent as string=""
     ' Read and display the lines from the file until the end 
     ' of the file is reached.

     Dim strArray() as string=Nothing

Do
   Array.Clear(strArray,0,strArray.Length)
   line = sr.ReadLine()

   strArray=line.split(" ")     'To read Every Word Seperated by a Space
   For i=0 to strArray.Count-1

       'Checks StartsWith and EndsWith "       - Eg. Ashi likes "firefox"
       If strArray(i).StartsWith("""") and strArray(i).EndsWith("""") then

          'Replace the string in "firefox" with TextBox1 text 
          line.Replace("""" & strArray(i) & """",trim(TextBox1.Text))

       End If
   FullContent = FullContent & line      'Append the changes to full content
   Next


 Loop Until line Is Nothing
   sr.Close()

   'Now you can write the FullContent Back to Txt File which has the replaced changes
   'writeFunction(FullContent)

   'If you want to display, then
   msgbox(FullContent)


Catch E As Exception
     ' Let the user know what went wrong.
     Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
     Console.WriteLine(E.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Try googling vb.net + streamreader and vb.net + streamwriter examples, that should give you want you want.

Comment: I know how to read a file.. but i don't know how to read in quotation marks after if finds the word name.